# get rid of “cannot find Symbol” error in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Before everything was fine but since some time i get "cannot find Symbol” when i try to compile.
The errors are on my own classes.

[image]

If i jump to source and then click the error icon i get this:

[image]

But the constructor already exists.
I have no idea of how to get rid of it. I did a lot of searching but none of the solutions like clean worked.

My project is under VCS which i don't really understand (how to set up etc). So maybe it has to do something with that. I only don't know how to get rid of it. Can someone help?

edit:
Here is the zip of the project folder and one folder that includes a library that is used.
I try to compile with build artifacts.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17630770/temp/doekeLibsArchive.zip

I hope someone can give it a try. I would love to continue on this project.

Comment: Are your classes under a `source root` (blue colored folder)? Are they in another maven module, with a correct dependency?

Comment: You mentioned that the 'clean' did not work. By that did you mean that the 'Invalidate Caches and Restart' did not work ? 

In my experience, when I get that error, re-importing the maven project seems to fix that issue (assuming ofc that it's maven that you are using).

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes it's under a blue folder called 'src'. And what do you mean by "Are they in another maven module, with a correct dependency?"?

Comment: @Ashutosh Jindal  i meant 'build artifacts' and then 'clear', but i also did 'invalidate caches and restart' and that didn't work either.

Comment: What happens if you create a new Intellij Project and import this module into it ?

Comment: I have no idea of how to set up the artifacts and compile then. My src folder is empty as supposed i get. And if i do right mouse and click "compile module" then nothing happens.

Comment: If i send the directory, will you have the same problem?

Comment: Where can you see the class BezierVertex exists? Is it as source or is it in a jar? If it's in a jar, how exactly is this jar configured as a dependency in your project: for example, project library, global library or via maven (if you have a pom.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from the fact you have two BezierVertex classes,

- a public one nl.doekewartena.path.BezierVertex
- and a nested one nl.doekewartena.path.BezierVertexPath.BezierVertex

when you are inside BezierVertexPath, intellij is right nl.doekewartena.path.BezierVertexPath.BezierVertex does not have the constructor shown on your screenshot, it is nl.doekewartena.path.BezierVertex which has it, so you should use the fully qualified name of that class.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks. The nested one was first named BezierVertexCap, don't know how the name changed.